# Trouble creating an HtmlDocument in C# using only a string

Tags: c#, string, dom

When I Googled the problem myself, people suggest to do it this way:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser;
web.DocumentText = htmlString;
HtmlDocument doc = web.Document;
```

This leaves doc as null. Any idea what could be going wrong? Debugging in Visual Studio seems to tell me that this:

```
web.DocumentText = htmlString;
```

doesn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: You need to wait for it to load.

Comment: @SLaks Yes. A lot of websites have said the same thing. I put a while loop in the program that runs until the WebBrowser's ready state is 'Complete'. Not much luck. I should mention that I am programming this as a console application - does that change anything?

Comment: You need an STA thread and a message loop for this to work with a console app. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/18675926/1768303